# passing variable with multiple values seperated by comma to sql statement through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've looked all over the interwebs, and cannot find that simple answer I'm looking for - possibly because it doesn't exist, but.. possibly because I don't know the correct terms to search for.

ok, so, i've got a variable - it's actaully a key value pair in an array that i'm passing into my function. the key is args[comments_mentioned] and the value is dynamically generated for me - it's ALWAYS going to be number, separated by commas (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5)

so, just to be super clear:

```
         $args[comments_mentioned] == "1,2,3,4"; //could be any amount of number, not just 1,2,3,4,5
```

i'd like to pass this into a sql statement as a variable to use in an "IN" clause, like so:

```
         $sr_sql = <<<SQL
         SELECT *
         FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
         WHERE meta_value = %s
         AND comment_ID in ($args[comments_mentioned])
         ORDER BY meta_id DESC
         SQL;
```

Then, Prepare it using the wordpress prepare and get results

```
        $sr_query = $wpdb->prepare( $sr_sql, $args[user_id]) );
        //receive the correct sql statement, and plug 'er in.
        $sr_comment_rows = $wpdb->get_results($sr_query);
```

and run my foreach loop:

```
        foreach ($sr_comment_rows as $sr_comment) {
            $sResults .= 'do something with $sr_comment';
        }
```

now, i realize the code above won't work - i can't just pass the variable in there like that. BUT, i can't pass it as a string (%s), because it wraps it in '1,2,3,45', and so it looks for the entire string, and not each number. I can't pass it as an int (%d), because of the commas...

In other posts, they mentioned create a temp table or variable, but, i'm not sure if that's the correct way to do it in mysql, or how to reference it once I do.

so, how do I do this? preference for actual code that works ;)

Thank you for reading and helping out!

Comment: Normalise your database properly, and this problem wouldn't even exist; otherwise look at MySQL's FIND_IN_SET() function

Comment: Mark: tell me more about normalizing :)

Comment: Normalizing can't be explained in a short answer, but google it and there's plenty of explanations out there

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you cannot normalize your data, is to enclose your string in commas such that it be `",1,2,3,4,"` and then you could do:

```
AND LOCATE( CONCAT(',',comment_ID,',') , ($args[comments_mentioned]) )
```

which will match if it finds a eg. `',3,'` in `',1,2,3,4,'` (Using 3 as an example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be enough:

```
$params = $args[comments_mentioned];
$table = $wpdb->commentmeta;
$sr_sql = "
         SELECT *
         FROM $table
         WHERE meta_value = %s
         AND comment_ID in ($params)
         ORDER BY meta_id DESC
         ";
```

It will be result something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_on_variable
WHERE meta_value = %s
         AND comment_ID in (1,2,3,4)
         ORDER BY meta_id DESC
```

If your mainly issue is regarding the in clause, so you will not have problems if you use double quotes and single variable as illustrated above.